# creating a matrix from data

Tags: r, stata

I have a data that has three columns which look like this:

```
ppl loc1 loc2 
 1   US  CH   
 1   US  KR  
 1   US  CAN 
 1   CAN KR
 1   KR  CH
 1   CH  US
 1   CAN CH
 1   US  US
```

I want to create a matrix that looks something like this:

```
       US CH KR CAN
    US 1  2  1  1  
    CH 2  0  1  1
    KR 1  1  0  0
   CAN 1  1  1  0
```

Any suggestions would be amazing.

Comment: Use `table(df1[-1])`

Comment: Or `xtabs(~ loc1 + loc2, dat)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stata answer:

```
clear 
input ppl str3 (loc1 loc2) 
 1   US  CH   
 1   US  KR  
 1   US  CAN 
 1   CAN KR
 1   KR  CH
 1   CH  US
 1   CAN CH
 1   US  US
 end 

 tab loc1 loc2, matcell(whatever) 

 mat li whatever 

whatever[4,4]
    c1  c2  c3  c4
r1   0   1   1   0
r2   0   0   0   1
r3   0   1   0   0
r4   1   1   1   1
```

See `help matrix` for adding row and column names.

Answer (score 1):

R answer:

You can `matrix` for numeric vectors only. in your case since you have strings, you should use `data.frame` like so:

```
ppl <- rep(1,8)
loc1 <- c("US", "US", "US", "CAN", "KR", "CH", "CAN", "US")
loc2 <- c("CH","KR"  ,"CAN" ,"KR","CH","US","CH","US")

mat <- matrix(ppl, loc1, loc2) #error
df <- data.frame(ppl, loc1, loc2, stringsAsFactors = F)
> df
  ppl loc1 loc2
1   1   US   CH
2   1   US   KR
3   1   US  CAN
4   1  CAN   KR
5   1   KR   CH
6   1   CH   US
7   1  CAN   CH
8   1   US   US
```

Answer (score 1):

R answer:

This should work:
    y <- unique(data[,2])

```
x <- unique(data[,3])
mat <- matrix(NA,length(x),length(y))

for(i in 1:nrow(mat)){
  for(j in 1:rcol(mat)){
    mat[i,j] <- sum(as.numeric(data[,2] == y[j] & data[,3] == x[i]))
  }
}
```